# Python: Long running streaming task in the server request/response lifecycle

Tags: python, django

How do I keep a long running script alive outside of the request/response lifecycle when that script is initiated by an HTML/AJAX request?

**Background:**

I have a Django app with a specific endpoint that streams results back to the client using [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects). In general this is working well. I have a series of generators that save each result to the database, yield their result to the StreamingHttpResponse, and the client displays each result appropriately as soon as it is received.

The problem arises when the client connection is unexpectedly lost. This causes the script to stop abruptly because Django closes the connection. I would like to come up with some mechanism by which that long running script can continue to execute so that all results can be processed and saved to the database. Then the user can retrieve the results after they regain a connection to the server.

**Code**

Here is the general structure of the current code:

```py
def ajax_stream_results(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    params = data['parameters']
    def results_generator(params):
        # Process result 1
        result1 = param1 * xyz
        # Save result 1 to database
        db_save(result1)
        # Stream result1 to client
        yield result1
            .
            .
            .
        #Process result 32
        result32 = param32 * xyz
        # Save result 32 to database
        db_save(result32)
        # Stream result32 to client
        yield result32
    return StreamingHttpResponse(results_generator(params))
```

The `results_generator` will save results to the database, yield each consecutive result and continue streaming data while the client conection is live. In an ideal world, we can find a solution to keep the `results_generator` going so that data can be saved to the database even if the client connection fails and the results can no longer be streamed to the client.

**Requirement:**

The solution should allow streaming of results (which we currently have), but also keep the script alive to continue processing results even if the client stream dies unexpectedly.

**Simplicity of Solution:**

I would like to keep this solution as simple as possible. It seems like this would be a relatively common problem, but my search results are only yielding very complex solutions. Even though I am using Django, I think the answer to my question would be relevant to any Python client/server library.

I know that the most current version of Django supports async/websockets, but upgrading would be a massive code refactor. I know that I could implement some sort of queuing (celery), but that seems entirely too complex for a single endpoint with one script, and I think we might loose the ability to stream results as well.

**Any solution:**

If there are truly no simple solutions to both stream results and keep the script alive, send me your best/favorite complex solutions! ;-)

Comment: Can you add an example of the generators that you are using to save and yield results? The entire view if possible

Comment: @IainShelvington I added some pseudo code to illustrate the general structure of the current method.